# How to create a ListView with Cards that adjust their size based on relative constraints?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `FractionallySizedBox` to take advantage of its ability to perform relative sizing.
Right now it returns to the `ListView.builder`, but I also tried putting it as a wrapper to `Card` widget (returning it instead as the main widget to the `ListView.builder`), I tried returning it as the child to the `GestureDetector`, all have failed miserably to obtain the output I'm hoping to get, which is 3 or n cards that take n percent of the container they're in, without having to manually set a fixed size.

How should I correctly use the `Widget`?

As per current configuration I get error:

```
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderFractionallySizedOverflowBox#d0391
```

Because:

```
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
```

The same error, height being infinity, also presents itself when I put `FractionallySizedBox` elsewhere (as decribed above), even when is contained inside a clearly sized widget.

This is my `State` class:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: .3,
              widthFactor: .8,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("tapped");
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100.0,
                          height: 100.00,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(75.0)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(blurRadius: 7.0, color: Colors.black)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

And this is the desired output:

[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FractionallySizedBox can not work with list view because it has Infinite hight and FractionallySizedBox take parents hight friction, so it will give you Infinite hight issue.

you can use Container instead of it in following manner.

```
  child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            // replace with container
            // keep 0.29 fraction to avoid scroll  
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.29,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10,
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer!  I applied these changes and it works perfectly.